# No calendar notifications after gingerbread on galaxy s 4G

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s, notifications, calendar

I updated my Galaxy S 4G to Gingerbread, followed by a factory reset. Now I don't get any calendar notifications even though the appropriate boxes have been selected in the Settings menu for the calendar app (no  pop-ups, no notifications in bar, no sound or vibrate). Google calendar, syncs perfectly.